# Light box blink when it call from datatable page 2

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, lightbox, x-editable

I am using jquery data tables with x-editable and i have one column with buttons when button press it is call confirmation lightbox, It is working properly.

But When datatable is redraw or move to previous page it not display just blink and hide it self

Code for lightbox in  is bellow :

```
<td><button type=button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-round target_delete_model" data_send_id="<?= $call_row['id']; ?>"><i class=fa-remove></i></button></td>
```

Code for calling light box using jquery :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
function RowSetup(){

//Delete model toggle code
$(".target_delete_model").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();     
    $("#delete_id").val($(this).attr("data_send_id"));
    $("#mySmallModal").modal("toggle");
    return false;
}); }
$("#datatable3").dataTable({
    sPaginationType: "bs_full",
    fnPreDrawCallback: function() {
        $(".dataTables_filter input").addClass("form-control input-large").attr("placeholder", "Search"), $(".dataTables_length select").addClass("form-control input-small")
    },
    oLanguage: {
        sSearch: "",
        sLengthMenu: "<span>_MENU_ entries</span>"
    },
    bJQueryUI: !1,
    bAutoWidth: !1,
    sDom: "<'row'<'col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 text-center'l><'col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-center'T><'col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 text-center'f>r>t<'row-'<'col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12'i><'col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12'p>>",
    oTableTools: {
        sSwfPath: "assets/plugins/tables/datatables/tabletools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
        aButtons: [{
            sExtends: "print",
            sButtonText: '<i class="st-printer s16 vat"></i> Print',
            aButtons: ["print"]
        }, {
            sExtends: "xls",
            sButtonText: '<i class="im-file-excel s16 vat"></i> XLS',
            aButtons: ["xls"]
        }, {
            sExtends: "pdf",
            sButtonText: '<i class="im-file-pdf s16 vat"></i> PDF',
            aButtons: ["pdf"]
        }, {
            sExtends: "csv",
            sButtonText: '<i class="im-file-xml s16 vat"></i> CSV',
            aButtons: ["csv"]
        }, {
            sExtends: "copy",
            sButtonText: '<i class="im-copy s16 vat"></i> Copy',
            aButtons: ["copy"]
        }]
    },"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
        RowSetup(); }
});
});
```

Code of lightbox division :

```
              <div class="modal fade" id="mySmallModal" tabindex=-1 role=dialog aria-labelledby=mySmallModalLabel aria-hidden=true>

            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

              <div class=modal-content>

                <div class=modal-header>

                  <button type=button class=close data-dismiss=modal aria-hidden=true>&times;</button>

                  <h4 class=modal-title id=mySmallModalLabel>Are you sure to delete ?</h4>

                </div>

                <div class=modal-body>

                  <p>Are you sure to delete this record permanently ?</p>

                </div>

                <div class=modal-footer>
                    <form action="delete.php" method="post">

                    <button type=button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss=modal>Close</button>
                    <button type=submit class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
                  </form>
                </div>

              </div>

              <!-- /.modal-content -->

            </div>

            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->

          </div>
```